# Track in_app_purchase event and subscription changes in Android App in Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, in-app-subscription

I linked Firebase, Analytics and PlayStore to track in_app_purchase events with Firebase SDK in my android app. This works fine, the in_app_purchase event is created.

But how is it possible to know, if free trial has been ended, or if user canceled subscription while free trial? How is it possible to know, that subscription has been renewed.

I see that this is difficult, because if user ended trial in PlayStore, it does not mean that he starts my app ever again. So when should it be logged?

This also has impact to Google Ads: I would of course like to see, if users who started subscription in a certain campaign stayed, or if they canceled the subscription.